# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A company has 2 plants A & B producing computers. There are 40 employees in A and 15 in B. 4 employees are randomly selected to fill out a benefits questionnaire. 
A. what is the probability that none of those are selected from plant B?
B. What is the probability that all 4 of the selected employees are from planet B?

For A I did (40 4) being that only plant A employees are being selected from. For B I did (15 4) because all the employees are soley from plant B. I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this problem?

Comment: You say a sample of 4, so the probability that all 5 come from plant B is a typo, or not?

Answer (score 0):

In order for no employees to be selected from B, you can only select A people. Find all of the probabilities and multiply them together.

(40/55) x (39/54) x (38/53 x (37/52) x (36/51) will give you the probability of only A people.

For them all to be selected from B, the probability is (15/55) x (14/54) x (13/53) x (12/52) x (11/51), as the time you are selecting the second person, there should only be 14 left proided you piced someone from B the first time. The third time, there should only be 13 left in be, providd you picked B the other 2 times. Etc, etc, etc.